# HTTP Post is not returning desired JSON

Tags: android, file-upload, httpurlconnection

I am uploading images to server using `HttpURLConnection` from Android. I've used `HttpPost` and `HttpClient` along with `MultipartEntity` and it was working fine. But they are now deprecated in Android therefore I had to use `HttpURLConnection` instead. But the call is returning `HTML` instead of JSON.
Below is the code of uploading file

```
private void uploadFile(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
        throws IOException {
    String fileName = uploadFile    .getName();
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                    + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
            .append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(
            "Content-Type: "
                    + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
            .append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();

    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
}
```

And before this, `prepareUpload` is called. Here it is

```
private void prepareUpload(String requestMethod) throws IOException {
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();
    outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
            true);
}
```

Inreturn, it is not uploading image and returns some HTML data which is not displaying in browser. I've checked this in Postman and it is working fine.
Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");

Comment: Do I have to replace it from `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary)` or add it?